# Getting pip to work on Amazon ec2 after you've updated to python 3.4

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-3.4

I'm building a Django website on an Amazons EC2 instance. So far, so good. I am, however, using Python 3.4 and Django 1.8. By default, Amazon has their instances set to Python 2.7, but you can update this with two commands.

```
sudo yum install python34
```

then
    sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.4

to install python 3.4, and set it as the default python for the instance. However, while you're using python 3.4, you can't use pip. For whatever reason, alternatives broke pip when I changed the version of python I'm using. I get it back when I switch to python 2.7
    sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python2.7

However, the version of pip that 2.7 uses won't install the newest Django. It also wont update to a newer version of pip. So instead I try and install pip into the 3.4 alternative.

```
sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.4
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.1.tar.gz#md5=62a9f08dd5dc69d76734568a6c040508
tar -xvf pip*.gz
cd pip*
sudo python setup.py install
```

Which finally gets me the error - Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
   from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Which is impressive, because setuptools is packaged as a basic part of python. At this point, I'm wondering if there is any clean way of going forward, or if I'm going to have to make another independent installation of python that isn't broken.

Comment: One suggestion would be to try the anaconda distribution of python.   It doesn't really answer your question but it could be a way of moving forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run...

```
sudo yum install python34
```

...it will not install pip. So you also need to run...

```
sudo yum install python34-pip
```

Comment: Is it really that easy? I've settled on a different solution using dockers, but that would have saved me... days of work, a week ago..

Answer (score 2):

Some warning note first. Seems that you are using CentOS (or something similar due to use of `yum`) which actually uses Python2.6 for many of its tools so changing the `python` to use `python3` might actually break other things. Current best practice is to use explicit `python3` command when you need Python3.

That being said, Im not sure what `alternatives` command does however usually `pip` command is hardlinked to a Python executable:

```
$ pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

You can see that if you `cat` the content of the `pip` command:

```
$ cat `which pip` | head -n 1
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

So changing your default `python` to use Python3 might have some negative side-effects due to that.

There is however another way to use pip - use it as a python module.

```
$ python -m pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

When you use that approach, you remove any ambiguity to which Python version pip is currently using since you trigger it via Python itself. That should fix your problem.

Alternatively, you might also want to consider using a virtual environment. In that case your default system Python can remain to be Python2 however in your venv you can use Python3:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10

$ virtualenv --python=`which python3` venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ python --version
Python 3.5.0
```